# Grails domain object derived property not updated after save

Tags: grails, grails-orm, derived

I am using a derived field in Grails domain class:

```
BigDecimal expectedDurationHrs

static mapping = {

    expectedDurationHrs formula: 'time_to_sec(timediff(expected_end_date, expected_start_date )) / 3600'
}
```

This allows me to query for this duration. The problem is that when I make a change to the start or end date the derived property does not get updated even after `.save(flush: true)` is called.

I would have expected after the save that the derived propert be updated. Similarly the domain instance stored in the Hibernate cache does not have the correct derived value.

Is there a way to have this refreshed and return the latest value?

cowper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess [events](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping) can help to solve your problem. Take a look at **beforeUpdate**.

Comment: Yes indeed, that is a solution. It seems like a little bit of duplication but can't find an alternative. thx